# What happens to someone who resists Faerie Glade?

Tags: spells, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, time, mage-the-awakening

The Time 5 Faerie Glade spell affects an area and speeds up or slows down time inside. However the spell can be resisted with a reflexive roll. Success on this roll would mean that that creature is unaffected, while time for everyone who failed to resist and for all objects is altered. I would expect this to result in effects similar to Acceleration or Chronos's Curse due to the change in relative time flow. But the description makes no mention of this issue and from the presented example it seems clear that this is not how the spell is intended to work.

How would such a situation play out?

Answer (score 1):

*Faerie Glade* is described as working like *Temporal Pocket* (Time ••••, p.265) except that it covers an area (while TP encompasses just the caster) and that time may be slower or faster within the spell's compass. *Temporal Pocket* says that no one may interact with the caster except for those with enough Time to pierce the bubble. In the case of *Faerie Glade*, since it covers an area, anyone who enters the space has a chance to enter the space the bubble covers.

Thus, the options are these: 
If you enter the area covered by a Faerie Glade, you make a contested, reflexive Composure + Gnosis roll.

1. If you fail this roll, you are within the bubble. Time passes for
   you at the rate the mage has set with the spell.
2. If you beat the
   mage's successes, you remain outside the effect of the spell and
   time passes as normal for you.

Those inside the bubble cannot interact with those outside the bubble, so there's no relative slow/fast time to address.